# mod_rewrite change directory to variable

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Not gonna complain about mod_rewrite, but regex makes me see sideways.

Okay how do I do the mod_rewrite for this:

```
http://domain.com/version1/pg/[VAR]/
```

to:

```
http://domain.com/version1/page.php?page=[VAR]
```

I've been going in circles all day with this.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^version1/pg/([^/]*)$ /version1/page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Basically, it will redirect `version1/pg/[VAR]` to `/version1/page.php?page=[VAR]`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That gives me a 404. (And I thank you for trying to answer this... and would definitely +rep any help I can get.)

Comment: OK. I've had a lot of trouble with mod_rewrite myself, I can understand your frustration ;-). Are you sure `page.php` exist in the directory? This might also be because Apache doesn't/can't read the .htaccess file (this happened to me, sometimes it can be a user-rights issue).

*If* you have access to the server as root, you can try to put this into the domain configuration file in your `/etc/apache`.

Comment: I checked the error log and it's looking for the version1/pg/ file and saying it doesn't exist. I think there is something wrong with the regex code.

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_rewrite module installed? For some reason, it doesn't do what it's supposed to do. The regex should be correct, I have used it before.

Comment: I figured it out and I have changed this question to reflect the question that worked. Upvoted you for helping!

Comment: I get it now, apparently your `.htaccess` file is in the `version1` directory, am I right? I wrote it as if `.htaccess` file was in the root, sorry.

Comment: If you solved it, let your question like it was, answer below to yourself and check it as "answered" later on.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^version1/pg/([^/]*)$ /version1/page.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Tell me if this works.

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

May I ask you to add the rewritelog in your question?

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out and I have changed this question to reflect the question that worked. Upvoted you for helping!

Comment: My pleasure! If you solved it, let your question like it was, answer below to yourself and check it as "answered" later on.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I have added the answer and I can select it in two days. But it worked and I am pleased! :) Could not have done it without the two of you guys who both helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^pg/([^/]*)$ page.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^pg/([^/]*)/$ page.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

So if the URL is: **mywebsite.com/version1/pg/sample/**

or

**mywebsite.com/version1/pg/sample**

It would rewrite the URL to:

**mywebsite.com/version1/page.php?page=sample**

Comment: Only one rule should work instead of two: **`RewriteRule ^pg/([^/]*)[/]?$ page.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]`**